# awk output format for average

Tags: awk, format

I am computing average of many values and printing it using `awk` using following script.

```
for j in `ls *.txt`; do
  for i in emptyloop dd cp sleep10 gpid forkbomb gzip bzip2; do
    echo -n $j $i" "; cat $j | grep $i | awk '{ sum+=$2} END {print sum/NR}'
  done;
  echo ""
done
```

but problem is, it is printing the value in in `1.2345e+05`, which I do not want, I want it to print values in round figure. but I am unable to find where to pass the output format.

EDIT: using `{print "average,%3d = ",sum/NR}'` inplace of `{print sum/NR}'` is not helping, because it is printing `"average,%3d 1.2345e+05"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need `printf` instead of simply  `print`. Print is a much simpler routine than printf is.

Answer (score 2):

```
for j in *.txt; do
    for i in emptyloop dd cp sleep10 gpid forkbomb gzip bzip2; do
        awk -v "i=$i" -v "j=$j" '$0 ~ i {sum += $2} END {printf j, i, "average %6d", sum/NR}' "$j"
    done
    echo
done
```

You don't need `ls` - a glob will do.

Useless use of `cat`.

Quote all variables when they are expanded.

It's not necessary to use `echo` - AWK can do the job.

It's not necessary to use `grep` - AWK can do the job.

If you're getting numbers like `1.2345e+05` then `%6d` might be a better format string than `%3d`. Use `printf` in order to use format strings - `print` doesn't support them.

The following all-AWK script might do what you're looking for and be quite a bit faster. Without seeing your input data I've made a few assumptions, primarily that the command name being matched is in column 1.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        cmdstring = "emptyloop dd cp sleep10 gpid forkbomb gzip bzip2";
        n = split(cmdstring, cmdarray);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            cmds[cmdarray[i]]
        }
    }
    $1 in cmds {
        sums[$1, FILENAME] += $2;
        counts[$1, FILENAME]++
        files[FILENAME]
    }
    END {
        for file in files {
            for cmd in cmds {
                printf "%s %s %6d", file, cmd, sums[cmd, file]/counts[cmd, file]
            }
        }
    }' *.txt
```